# adding a submenu to magento-backend-stores

Tags: php, xml, menu, magento2, submenu

I created a grid in Magento admin for managing FAQ's and now I need to add it as a submenu to Magento2 admin's store's menu, How can it be done? Can anyone help me? I tried out giving parent attribute in the menu.xml file and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**use parent="Magento_Backend::stores"**

```
<add id="Module_Test::settings" 
    title="ShopBy Settings" module="Module_Test" sortOrder="30" 
    parent="Magento_Backend::stores" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/test" 
    resource="Module_Test::test_config"/>
```

check : vendor\magento\module-backend\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml